# Enqueue script only when side widget is used

Tags: widgets, wp-enqueue-script

How would I go about using the following script only when the widget is used?

```
<?php

//sidedish slide script
function sidedish_slide_script() {

    wp_register_script('add-sd-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/form-slider/jquery-1.8.2.min.js', array('jquery'),'null', true );
    wp_register_script('add-sd-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/form-slider/formslider.js', array('jquery'),'null', true );
    wp_register_style('add-sd-css',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/form-slider/styles.css', '','','screen' );


    wp_enqueue_script ('add-sd-js');
    wp_enqueue_script ('add-sd-custom');
    wp_enqueue_style ('add-sd-css');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','sidedish_slide_script');


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

is_widget_active is what you want e.g.

```
function sidedish_slide_script() {
 wp_register_script('add-sd-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/form-slider/jquery-1.8.2.min.js', array('jquery'),'null', true );
 wp_register_script('add-sd-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/form-slider/formslider.js', array('jquery'),'null', true );
 wp_register_style('add-sd-css',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/form-slider/styles.css', '','','screen' );

 if ( is_active_widget( false, 'widget_id', $this->id_base, true ) ) {
  wp_enqueue_script ('add-sd-js');
  wp_enqueue_script ('add-sd-custom');
  wp_enqueue_style ('add-sd-css');
 }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','sidedish_slide_script');
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_widget

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation but I place this in my function.php file and my site goes blank. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: link correction: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_active_widget/